# What is the best strategy to allow an application to be themed by an customer and published for download?

Tags: c#, asp.net, build-automation, publish

I'm building an application in WPF (C# 4.0) that can be downloaded online for free on the internet.

If the user wants to customize this app (custom icon, color scheme, etc.) UI, he will have the option to configure colors, upload resources like icons and logos, change texts, etc., all done through the website.

My question is: what would be the best strategy to allow users to do this kind of customization, having the server build and package the application and later publishing so the user can download it.

Currently I'm accomplishing this using build script written in powershell, that are invoked by the webserver (IIS) using a custom HTTP handler I wrote. The build result is later sent to the user by email, with a link to download the application.

Comment: @Mitch as fastest and painless for the user as possible, without making my life a living hell

Answer (score 0):

Let them upload the artifacts et al and store them on the server (in a DB, or whatever).

Then when on system start, when the app initially launches, deploy them from the database in to the appropriate places within the application.

If they're changing CSS colors or whatever, then you can start with a CSS template that refers to the colors etc symbolically and regenerate the CSS.

This allows you to separate the changeable components, and also lets you even potentially upgrade the application while the existing changes remain in place.

Regenerate on restart lets you treat them all as if they're static resources, and odds are the start up time will be negligible.

You can also regenerate on demand.

Comment: It's a desktop app, there will be no CSS.